# Oracle - Executions Remaining

Tags: oracle, dynamic, calculation

So we will have this job run from the cron twice an hour between 7:00am - 5:00pm.   So the cron entry is something like:  00,30 7-17 * * *

This basically means the job will run up to 20 times per day.  In the stored procedure, the number of executions remaining is part of some calculation.  So:

```
At 7:00am, there are 20 executions remaining
At 7:30am, there are 19 executions remaining
At 8:00am, there are 18 executions remaining
At 8:30am, there are 17 executions remaining
```

And so on.  How can I determine the number of executions remaining, based on time alone?  Meaning, we do not want to store some variable or counter someplace on number of executions remaining.   And, say one is execution missed, perhaps some processing issues, then fine, it is missed.

If we can calculate the number of executions remaining dynamically in the code, then it will be self sufficient and not need to be maintained, etc., even if we pause the cron, when it starts again, it just does its calculation and continues.

Any ideas would be great, as we've not some up with any algorithms as of yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to calculate that. Here's one, by generating a calendar of executions and counting those still in the future:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) execs_remaining
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7/24 + (((LEVEL-1)*30)/1440) exec_date
          FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 21)
 WHERE SYSDATE < exec_date
```

Comment: I like this approach.   Have 2 questions:  Just to make sure I understand, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7/24 is the starting time, 7:00am.  Correct?   (((LEVEL-1)*30)/1440) is basically adding 30 minutes to the start time (7:00am), for 21 executions.   Correct?   And, say I run this process manually, maybe at some 45 minutes past the hour, it will still calculate properly, correct?

Comment: You have the idea, yes. You'll need to try a few tests to see if it works precisely how you want and adjust accordingly if there are some margin cases.